# Issues creating a typescript definition file

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm having issues creating a typescript definition file a 'simple' npm module.

Here are the details:

Issue: when I compile the typescript it get the following error:

```
play.ts(1,9): error TS2305: Module '"/to/the/dir/node_modules/geojson/geojson"' has no exported member 'GeoJSON'.
```

Module: geojson (https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson). 
The package only has one public function. it is in a file geojson.js:

```
  (function(GeoJSON) {
  GeoJSON.version = '0.3.0';
  GeoJSON.defaults = {};

  // The one and only public function.
  // Converts an array of objects into a GeoJSON feature collection
  GeoJSON.parse = function(objects, params, callback) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  (typeof module == 'object' ? module.exports : window.GeoJSON = {}));
```

The package.json includes

```
"main": "./geojson",
"name": "geojson",
//// I ADDED THIS TYPE DEF FILE
"typings": "./geojson.d.ts",
```

From this i gather

1. module name: geojson
2. parse: signature is parse(objects: any, params: any, callback?: any): any;
3. GeoJSON is an interface ?

My definition file is: geojson.d.ts

```
export declare module geojson {
    interface GeoJSON {
        parse(objects: any, params: any, callback?: any): any;
    }  
}
```

My tsconfig file is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5",
     "module": "system",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "removeComments": false,
     "noImplicitAny": false
    }
}
```

I'm trying to import (I've tried 1000 ways..) here are some:

```
import GeoJSON from 'geojson';
import geojson from 'geojson';
import {geojson} from geojson;
import geojson = require('geojson');
import GeoJSON = require('geojson');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no publicly available typings already - the correct type declaration in your case should be as per below.

You shouldn't be editing the `package.json` and instead should either consume typings using the `typings` tool or alternatively save the below type definition somewhere in your source folder as `something-or-other.d.ts`. I would also recommend adding `exclude: [ "node_modules" ]` to your `tsconfig.json` to prevent it from processing anything in the `node_modules` folder (currently it will recursively process everything).

The module doesn't have any namespace or interface per se. Keep in mind that in the file itself is a "namespace" (this is confusing at first if you are coming from .NET/Java, etc.)

```
declare module 'geojson' {
    export var version : string;
    export var defaults: Object;
    export function parse(data: Object, propreties: Object, callback?: Function) : Object;
}
```

Consume like this:

```
import * as geoJson from 'geojson';

var data = [
        { name: 'Location A', category: 'Store', lat: 39.984, lng: -75.343, street: 'Market' },
        { name: 'Location B', category: 'House', lat: 39.284, lng: -75.833, street: 'Broad' },
        { name: 'Location C', category: 'Office', lat: 39.123, lng: -74.534, street: 'South' }
      ];

var result = geoJson.parse(data, {Point: ['lat', 'lng']});
console.log(result);
```

Generates this JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
var geoJson = require('geojson');
var data = [
    { name: 'Location A', category: 'Store', lat: 39.984, lng: -75.343, street: 'Market' },
    { name: 'Location B', category: 'House', lat: 39.284, lng: -75.833, street: 'Broad' },
    { name: 'Location C', category: 'Office', lat: 39.123, lng: -74.534, street: 'South' }
];
var result = geoJson.parse(data, { Point: ['lat', 'lng'] });
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
c:\code\tmp\geojson>node build\main.js
{ type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features:
   [ { type: 'Feature', geometry: [Object], properties: [Object] },
     { type: 'Feature', geometry: [Object], properties: [Object] },
     { type: 'Feature', geometry: [Object], properties: [Object] } ] }
```

Have a look at a blog I wrote with more info about typings discovery, etc:

http://ivanz.com/2016/06/07/how-does-typescript-discover-type-declarations-definitions-javascript/

This is a sort of "ambient" type declaration that will work as the file it's in is included in the file. It tells TypeScript "Hey, TypeScript - there exists a module called geojson which has the following members". In your case the module will be a NPM one living in `node_modules`.

There are other ways to write typings if you were for example doing it for a local javascript file (not an npm package) or as an NPM package author, which boils down to writing an "external" module type declaration which has a file name (`module.d.ts` if you have `module.js` and is in the same directory as the `module.js`). In such cases the declaration will not include a "declare module" bit, because it's bound to the .js file directly.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the module definition you wrote are not getting exported (made available publicly).

```
   declare module 'geojson' {
        export interface GeoJSON {
            parse(objects: any, params: any, callback?: any): any;
        }
   }
```

you should then be able to consume it using:

```
import {GeoJSON} from 'geojson';
```

<del>have you considered using the typings already available for this library at DefinitelyTyped?</del> EDIT: as Paul mentioned in the comments the only available typings seem to be for the GeoJson schema not the library

Comment: How come this answer got voted down? Did you try this Paul?

Comment: Paul can you explain why you down-voted my answer. While I agree that @Ivan's is more complete I don't think it deserved a down-vote

Comment: @WayneRiesterer I down-voted it, because the module declaration line was incorrect (it was redacted since) and also because it doesn't actually work. Yes the import statement won't error, but beyond that - it won't work. Please correct me if I am wrong and I will undo my downvote immediately :)

Comment: @tadwork It was me downvoting it. See the above comment ^^

Comment: @tadwork the typedef file on dt is for the geojson schema (http://geojson.org/) not the npm package. thanks for the help